# Firefox blocking SSL, works in all other browsers

Tags: ssl

I've just installed SSL on my server (shared reseller package).

Its my first time using SSL and I couldn't get it working properly in Chrome or Firefox. Obviously this was because many of the CSS/JS/etc. links were not "https", but "http".

I've modified the necessary files and now Google Chrome is displaying a nice green padlcok and confirms my pages (checkout/login/controls/accountools).php are all secure.

However, if I open up the page in Firefox, instantly I get:

```
This Connection is Untrusted

You have asked Firefox to connect
securely to www.domain.co.uk, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.
          Normally, when you try to connect securely,
sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are
going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.

What Should I Do?

If you usually connect to

this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is
trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.
```

Contrast this to Google:

```
Your connection to domain.com is encrypted with 256-bit encryption.
The connection uses TLS 1.0

The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and DHA_RSA as the key exchange mechanism
```

What's more, the other browsers (MSIE, Safari, Opera), didn't bat an eyelid even when the pages were technically "unsecure" due to the CSS/JS/images, etc.

I know I can simply add my site to the trusted list in Firefox, but this doesn't look good for me when someone comes along and sees "UNTRISTED WEB SITE" before they even get to the checkout/login pages etc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is that an auto-message? I've not accepted any replies to my 5 previous questions because none of them have provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complain to the iSP. The SSL certificate isn't properly signed.

Comment: The SSL is from Comodo, who are a trusted CA. I think the problem may be that intermediate certificates are not installed. Firefox requires them to be installed. I used this site: http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/ and it says it was "unable to get the local issuer of the certificate" and "Normally this indicates that not all intermediate certificates are installed". My web host has not responded to my ticket, which is odd because they're normally good. UK2 are a large hosting comapny so I'm not woried about scams.